# Change the Value in a Column to Change from a String to a Number on Insery

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which I have cut down into basic fields, it is called Customer

### ID | Name   | Type

1 | Smith     | 2

I want to create a trigger on INSERT that will change the value of the inserting Type, into a number example:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (Name,Type) VALUES ('Jones', 'Recommended')
```

The Type field should be a number and it is set as an INT column. I do not want to change this away from INT.

How can I force the word Recommended to be changed to ‘0’ a zero?

Comment: Why are you not just inserting `0`? Seems like an XY Problem. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? What about other values? Your example has the value `2` for Type.

Comment: This is just an example from a large import of data, I have broken it right down to the issue only. The whole is more complex.

Comment: The 2 is a number that would be the normal INT value inserted BTW.

Comment: *"The whole is more complex. "* Then that's what you should be telling us about

Comment: The whole does not have a problem. It is just data going into this field/column that is. I could have asked the question and simply put it:- How do I change a string to a number when the column is set as a type INT. However I thought that putting as I did would make it easier to explain and be understood.

Comment: The "simple" solution would be fix your `INSERT`: `INSERT INTO Customer (Name,Type) VALUES ('Jones', 0);` Fix that, there isn't an issue with trying to put the wrong data type into the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Theory :**

This is the trigger :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CustomersInsert] ON [dbo].[Customer]
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS BEGIN 

    INSERT Into Customer (Name,Type)
    SELECT
    inserted.[Name],
    Isnull([Types].Id, 0)
    FROM inserted
    Left Join [dbo].[Types] on inserted.[Type] = [Types].Caption
END
```

The `[dbo].[Types]` is for keep Types.

**But in real :**

You can't execute `INSERT INTO Customer (Name,Type) VALUES ('Jones', 'Recommended')` 
because `Type` is `INT` and `'Recommended'` is not.